# how parse the between of when the right could come after a repeating pattern?

Tags: f#, fparsec

How would you use existing FParsec functionality to find a repeating consecutive pattern in the rightmost tag?

It's a legitimate possibility in this context.  Pre-parsing + escaping might work, but is there a better solution?  Do we need to write a new forward combinator, and if so, what does it look like?

```
#r"""bin\debug\FParsecCS.dll"""
#r"""bin\debug\FParsec.dll"""

open FParsec

let str = pstring
let phraseEscape = pchar '\\' >>. pchar '"'
let phraseChar = phraseEscape <|> (noneOf "|\"\r\n]")    // <- this right square bracket needs to be removed
let phrase = manyChars phraseChar

let wrapped = between (str"[[") (str"]]".>>newline) phrase 

run wrapped "[[some text]]\n"  // <- works fine

// !! problem
run wrapped "[[array[] d]]\n"    // <- that means we can't make ']' invalid in phraseChar

// !! problem
run wrapped "[[array[]]]\n"      // <- and this means that the first ]] gets match leaving a floating one to break the parser
```

Comment: @Vesa.A.J.K: I didn't define the language, so I don't have the luxury of doing my own thing.  Apart from this odd corner case, it's very readable and almost context free.  Some of this work may make its way into FSharp.Data, but I'm not ready for that yet.  ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to be answering my own question, but...

See composable function **phraseTill**, and the **pend** parser that is passed to it of **(notFollowedBy(s"]]]")>>.(s"]]"))**

```
#r"""bin\debug\FParsecCS.dll"""
#r"""bin\debug\FParsec.dll"""

open FParsec

let s = pstring
let phraseChar = (noneOf "\r\n")   
let phrase = manyChars phraseChar
/// keep eating characters until the pend parser is successful
let phraseTill pend = manyCharsTill phraseChar pend

/// when not followed by tipple, a double will truly be the end
let repeatedTo repeatedPtrn ptrn = notFollowedBy(s repeatedPtrn)>>.(s ptrn) 
let wrapped = (s"[[")>>.phraseTill (repeatedTo "]]]" "]]")
run wrapped "[[some text]]]"
run wrapped "[[some text]]"
```

NB. if you try this out in FSharp Interactive (FSI), make sure you have at least one "run wrapped" line when you send your text to FSI to be evaluated (ie. right-click 'Execute In Interactive').  The type only gets inferred / pinned on application in this example.  We could have provided explicit definitions at the risk of being more verbose.